# What if I disable "high performance order storage" in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders, woocommerce-theming

What if I disable "high performance order storage" in WooCommerce with 500+ daily orders and 5k+ daily traffic? What will be the side effects on the website?

There are some Plugins I am using and it's showing error that these plugins are not supporting HPOS and making issues in the website like rejecting orders and some other UX issues.
What could be the effects of disabling HPOS or any other solution?

Comment: The effect of disabling it, would be that you get none of the performance improvements it provides any more. _How_ "slow" things will actually become, with your order volumes and traffic, you'll have to see. Will depend on the hardware & system configuration as well.